# Dragging and releasing element to mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mouseevent

I'm trying to code a script, where it automatically drags and releases the "ball" element (which is already draggable) when you click. I'm not trying to ***reposition*** the element, I'm trying to actually *simulate* the drag and release when you click on your mouse.

So, I want the script to:

1. Find and define your mouse position when you click
2. Drags and drops the draggable element to the defined position

Here is the code for the "ball" element:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <p>Drag the ball.</p>

  <img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/soccer-gate.svg" id="gate" class="droppable">

  <img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball">

  <script>
    let currentDroppable = null;

    ball.onmousedown = function(event) {

      let shiftX = event.clientX - ball.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      let shiftY = event.clientY - ball.getBoundingClientRect().top;

      ball.style.position = 'absolute';
      ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
      document.body.append(ball);

      moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

      function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
        ball.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
        ball.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
      }

      function onMouseMove(event) {
        moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

        ball.hidden = true;
        let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        ball.hidden = false;

        if (!elemBelow) return;

        let droppableBelow = elemBelow.closest('.droppable');
        if (currentDroppable != droppableBelow) {
          if (currentDroppable) { // null when we were not over a droppable before this event
            leaveDroppable(currentDroppable);
          }
          currentDroppable = droppableBelow;
          if (currentDroppable) { // null if we're not coming over a droppable now
            // (maybe just left the droppable)
            enterDroppable(currentDroppable);
          }
        }
      }

      document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

      ball.onmouseup = function() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        ball.onmouseup = null;
      };

    };

    function enterDroppable(elem) {
      elem.style.background = 'pink';
    }

    function leaveDroppable(elem) {
      elem.style.background = '';
    }

    ball.ondragstart = function() {
      return false;
    };
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by draggable in your point 2  in moving the element, is it just that it is to take some time (if so, what defines the speed of 'drag') rather than just leap to the clicked position instantly?

Comment: I want it to move on to the clicked position instantly

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, in what sense is it dragged then?

Comment: The script drags and drops the element instantly.

Comment: I don't want it to just reposition the element

Comment: You want the ball to be in the position where mouse is clicked?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to just reposition the ball, I want to actually simulate drag and drop